# Changing network config during CentOS netinstall

Tags: networking, centos, system-installation

I cannot find a way to change the networking information during a CentOS netinstall, when using the URL installation method.

I always use a netinstall, and occasionally fat-finger the network information. Once you try to access the URL, it will error if it cannot get to the image - but it will not let you go back and change the network configuration.

Is there anyway to get to a shell or reset the information, without just having to reboot?

It seems odd you cannot change this - just something I would like to know for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no, you can't reset the network settings that Anaconda asked before.

However, you can set the network settings by changing grub menu entries or use kickstart file directly.

When choosing "Install or upgrade an existing system" during grub, you can press "Tab" to edit the option by appending the following text into entry `append` like this:

```
append initrd=initrd.img ip=<ip> dns=<dns> gateway=<gw> text
```

Here's the [full reference](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Anaconda_Boot_Options?rd=Anaconda/Options) for all options you can use.

If you use netinstall every time, you should think about using kickstart file to formalized all the options to perform silent OS installation. Here's a good [guide](http://blog.crazytje.be/create-a-kickstart-netinstall-with-centos/).

Comment: I figured as much. Good point on the kickstart file too.